# Dynamic cast to uknown class java

Tags: java, casting

Every other question of this type is answered by suggesting using switch or if-else statements and I would like to avoid at all.
So I have a client class with two overloaded methods which uses two different instances of certain interface implementations. For simplicity:

```
public interface MyInterface<R extends Register> {

Object myServiceMethod(R register);
```

Then there is a client with two methods

```
    public Double methodName(Class1 name1)
    public Double methodName(Class2 name2)
```

Where both Class1 and Class2 implements Register. And what I need to do in MyService implementation is to call proper method without knowing a priori which class will it get

```
public class MyServiceImplementation implements MyInterface<Register>{
@Override
public Object myServiceMethod(Register myRegister){
return myClient.methodName(*and here is a place for magic)
}
```

I need to do something like:

```
return myClient.methodName((myRegister.getClass()) myRegister);
```

But since this is illegall - my question goes here.

Comment: try `myRegister.getClass().cast(myRegister)`

Comment: does Class1 and Class2 extend the same base class? are the implementations of the methods different?

Comment: Why don't you use Object class? And then cast it to respective classes.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that both Class1 and Class2 implements Register

Comment: so why do you want do differentiate them?

Comment: Because they have different variables in them. myClient.methodName is using, for example, Class1's int a and int b and do some stuff with it while using Class1 and Class2's String s and int c while using Class2

Comment: In this case, the best practice is to have 2 implementations of `MyInterface` like `MyServiceImplementation1 implements MyInterface<Class1>` and `MyServiceImplementation2 implements MyInterface<Class2>`

Comment: can you move the method to the Register classes? there you can use polymorphism and avoid all conditionals... you would just do myRegister.methodName

Answer (score 0):

This smells of poor object-oriented design, but here's how to do what you're after. Basically, you seem to be trying to do run-time polymorphism at compile time, which doesn't work in Java. (Some dynamic languages, such as Groovy, can do it.) So you need to do the differentiation explicitly:

```
if (myRegister instanceOf Class1)
    myClient.methodName((Class1) myRegister);  // Selects this overload at compile time
else if (myRegister instanceOf Class2)
    myClient.methodName((Class2) myRegister);
else
    throw new RuntimeException("Unrecognized type: " + myRegister.getClass());
```

Comment: This is my current solution which I wanted to avoid but from the tone of your answer I understand that nothing better can be done. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Change your client code.

Change:

```
public Double methodName(Class1 name1)
public Double methodName(Class2 name2)
```

To:

```
public Double methodName(Register register)
```